Open URL and activate browser window
In my fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, running Wayland, when I run the command open https://google.com in the terminal to open the URL in the default browser, it works but the browser window is not raised.
Is there a trick to make it activate and raise the window to the front?
Thanks.

You could use xdotool windowraise, possibly.  Use the browser name instead of open, it will take focus..  i.e. firefox https://google.com or google-chrome https://google.com

"xdg-open https://www.google.com/" should open firefox if you have it installed.

What is the actual version info. There is no version simply called 24.

@David Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

Seems to be a bug in Wayland. After reading various posts, someone suggested switching over to Xorg. Did and it worked as expected.

Browser already open. It should raise the window to the front, it doesn't.

Please when adding info to a question add it to the question not as a comment.

Seems to be a bug in Wayland. After reading various posts, someone suggested switching over to Xorg. Did and it worked as expected.
Not only that, KeePassXC integration with the browser started working properly as well. Typically when the database is locked the app window should be raised to unlock it. Under Wayland it didn't happen. As soon as I switched to Xorg it did.
